# cannot load DLL after VS installer deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment

The C# application that I'm trying to deploy has two critical references, A.dll and B.dll.

First, I used InstallShield LE which includes everything (.dll's and .pdb's) in release folder into application files, application is deployed to different computers without problem. The app is about 6M after installation.

Then, I started to use VS installer, including "primary output" into application folder. I can see both A.dll and B.dll are included. After install the app on another computer, A and B exist in the installation directory too. When I run the application, it gives me "could not load file or assembly "B.dll" or one of its dependencies" error. B.dll only depends on .NET framework. The app is only 3M after installation because the installation directory has only the .dll's (no .pdb's).

Did I miss anything here? Any idea would be helpful, Thank you.

Edit:
The difference between A.dll and B.dll is that B.dll is compiled from a C++/cli program while A.dll is from C#. Does this make them different in deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Fusion log viewer on the target machine to determine why the DLL is not found.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx

Sometimes Fuslogvw can be a pain to get working, if so try restarting the machine, or see any of the blog posts about it

https://www.google.ca/search?q=fuslogvw.exe&oq=fuslog

I'm sure once you find the reason (in the logs) it will be obvious what the problem is with the MSI, but if not post your findings.

Comment: I tried VS installer deployment again, app works this time in one of the computer, still doesn't work in another one. I tried Fuglogvw, log on B.dll didn't say any failure, since it works on this computer now (i assume). This is very strange, I don't understand.

Comment: Jim, I just edited my question, please check it again. Thanks

Comment: Did you get a log entry for b.dll saying that it loaded successfully on the computer where it doesn't work?  You should log everything and not just errors to be sure that it's not just a logging failure.